# Post processing - image stabilisation

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, camcorder, linux, stabilisation

I own a [Panasonic HC-V130](http://goo.gl/mCkbQA). Recently I've read an article about image stabilisation in a computing magazine. Can this be achieved without a special camera?

I am using too much zoom to hold the camera still - causing the image to bounce up and down. Can I correct some of this shaking using software after? If possible can anyone suggest a few pieces of software that can achieve this - if possible a free one.

*I use windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux).*

Comment: Welcome user3258396 :) Please explain what you've read. I assume you are read about automatic hardware image stabilization, but you are asking for software - bit confusing. Please add more context to the question. So far I understand your question I'd suggest to use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) or [Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/at/products/fusion) via wine.

Comment: I mean where a video has been shot and say I am walking in the picture whilst shooting or I am using too much zoom to hold the camera still - causing the image to bounce up and down. Can I correct some of this shaking using software after - much like removing redeye or adjusting contrast? I'm talking about using no special hardware for shooting the video. Just that camera mentioned above and my PC after for post processing.

Comment: Possible, but in order to get a solid answer might be a good idea to add an _example shot_ or a better _description_ of your issue to your question.

Comment: look here: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/how-to-remove-little-camera-movements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe premiere and After effects have a stabilizer plugin with that does what you want. These are commercial applications.

The free Da vinci resolve lite also has a "stabilize option" (but I have never tried personally)

Comment: The answer seems to be yes it can be done. Thanks all! :-)

Comment: Search for youtube video with "adobe warp stabilizer" and you will see the plugin in action.

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg's [`vid.stab` filter](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/) works well.  You have to run it as a 2-pass process: detect, and then stabilize.  If you're going to do more with the video later, after stabilizing, output to a lossless format and then point your other tools at that.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe warp stabilizer, Mercalli pro, Mocha AE, Vegas Stablize, these are all either part of the NLE or separate plugins that work to stabilize a shot. In my experience, Mercalli is by far the best, and has simple options that you can customize depending on the type of stabilization.

With that in mind, I've found its really important to shoot at a higher frame rate and higher shutter speed to minimize motion blur as that is usually what makes post-processed video stabilization look wobbly among other things like shear. Up and down movement is probably the simplest to correct, but any footage that involves movement forward/backward / pans will have to be broken up into sections, or may not be stablizable due to the motion (will look weird) and too much would be cut off in the crop.